# jQuery addClass to all Elements with Class

Tags: jquery, find, each

I want to `addClass()` `strike` to class `priceis` **if** the class `specialprice` exists. Currently, it is only putting it on the *first* element, not on *every* element that appears on the page. I need it to check for *all* elements with the class `specialprice`.

```html
<font class="pricecolor colors_productprice specialprice">
    <span class="PageText_L483n">
        <font class="text colors_text"><b>Regular Price:<br> </b></font>
        <span id="priceis">$2,492<sup>.38</sup></span>
    </span>
</font>

<script>
    $('.specialprice').find('.priceis').addClass('strike');
</script>
```

Comment: There is no element with the class 'priceis' in the code.  I'm assuming `id="priceis"` should be `class="priceis"`.

Comment: `<span id="priceis">` should be `class` instead, right? For id you need `#priceis` instead

Comment: You are correct, I have updated code

Comment: The question seems to have been edited so that it reflects the answer - it should have remained unchanged to reflect the problem

Comment: I have suggested an edit to this effect^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your HTML is wrong

```
<span id="priceis">
```

You probably meant to set `class` instead of `id`.

```
<span class="priceis">
```

[Your current code will work if you fix your HTML.](http://jsfiddle.net/KzkcP/)

You might **[want to see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998305/why-isnt-my-hover-event-firing-in-jquery/3998427#3998427)**, it explains why a script doesn't work when included before the DOM elements.

Comment: I have fixed it it still only does it on the first 'specialprice' that appears.

Comment: @ToddN where does this script runs? `$(document).ready` ? It have to execute at least after all DOM nodes render. Put your script after all those elements.

Comment: BINGO!  You got it, it was not placed correclty in the document.ready.  My current code does indeed work correctly, thank you!

Answer (score 15):

maybe something like this? still not sure about the explanation of your question, not clear..

```
$(function() {
  $('.specialprice').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.priceis').addClass('strike');
  });
}
```

EDIT:
just realized maybe you wanted it like this?

```
$('.specialprice').each(function() {
  $(this).find('*').addClass('strike');
});
```

Answer (score 13):

`$('.specialprice.priceis').addClass('strike');` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.priceis').each(function(i, item) {

    var $item = $(item);

    if( $item.hasClass('specialprice') || $item.parents('.specialprice') )
    {
        $item.addClass('strike');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.specialprice').has('.priceis').addClass('strike');
```

Comment: This added class 'strike' with 'specialprice' not just the 'priceis'

Comment: @ToddN, im not sure what you mean